# Authentication in spring cloud gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am newbie to spring cloud. I am trying to integrate spring cloud gateway(**spring cloud Finchley.SR1**) just to authenticate and route my requests.

> My Application stack is as follows

- **Main Dashboard Application** built using spring mvc and angular. It has login page and a dashboard. Authentication is integrated in it which authenticates user credentials against database. I also use **hazelcast** for session replication in this app.
- Set of **Downstream services** which will be invoked once user logs into above dashboard and navigates inside it.
- An **API Gateway** built using spring cloud gateway: For now it does only routing.

```
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: customers
          uri: http://localhost:8282/customers
          predicates:
          - Path=/customers/**
          - Header=employeeId, \d+
          filters:
          - RewritePath=/customers/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
        - id: rates
          uri: http://localhost:8383/rates
          predicates:
          - Path=/rates/**
          filters:
          - RewritePath=/rates/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
```

> Need to implement following

- *First request will come to gateway I need to check if user is authenticated or not, if not authenticated then I need to show login page of Dashboard Application(i.e first app) or else allow user to proceed.*
- Once user logged in and navigating inside dashboard then api requests to downstream services will also go through **api gateway** I need authenticate these requests as well and send 403 status if user is not authenticated.

> I am not able to figure out how to handle these authentications in **spring cloud gateway app**. Is it possible to leverage hazelcast session replication that I added in **Main Dashboard App**, use it validate the user in gateway?

> Or is there any better approach using spring cloud suite tools that I can use it here. A sample app will be useful

Comment: I have similar requirement. I am able to redirect the request but not sure how can I authenticate the request. Were you able to do it using Spring Cloud Gateway? If yes,  Can you please share some idea how to get started with Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I customized AuthenticationWebFilter class in Spring Security 2.0.5.
And I customized ServerAuthenticationConverter class and SuccessHandler, FailureHandler and ReactiveAuthenticationManager class in AuthenticationWebFilter.
If you use Spring security, I recommend searching the WebFilter. 
I hope it helps.